# textRange selection MSIE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-selection

I can easily set the selection on 2+ elements programatically in Firefox,
But have had no success with IE so I hope anyone here can help me with this.

Comment: Neither chrome supports this too. I hope you found a solution for your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't support multiple concurrent selected TextRanges, whether programmatically or manually selected. You can have a [ControlRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537447(VS.85).aspx) of multiple selected elements, but not stretches of text.

It's possible for other browsers that embed the Web Browser control to [support multiple text ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536396(VS.85).aspx):

> Host applications can provide a multiple selection mechanism and can return a collection of TextRange objects that represents discontinuous selections.

But as of today IE doesn't, and I don't know of any other host application that does. Or indeed of any other browser than Firefox 3 that allows it.

Comment: Neither IE nor chrome. Only firefox supports multiple discontinuous selected ranges. I had code that highlighted search results and was disappointed that it only worked on firefox. Moreover, window.getSelection().addRange(r) changes the focus to the selected text in chrome. I wonder why the method was called addRange while it's possible to select only one range?