# How to enable multiple selection for text in internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, selection

How can I enable discontinuous multiple text selection in Internet Explorer? I tried IDM_MULTIPLESELECTION but that seems only to work for objects in edit mode and not for text.

FF3 seems to have multiple selection enabled by default and works by clicking the ctrl key.

I am using IE8. A code sample in any language is fine.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707315/textrange-selection-msie

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) within question ["textRange selection MSIE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707315/textrange-selection-msie)

> IE doesn't support multiple concurrent selected TextRanges, whether programmatically or manually selected. You can have a ControlRange of multiple selected elements, but not stretches of text.
>
> It's possible for other browsers that embed the Web Browser control to support multiple text ranges:
>
> > Host applications can provide a multiple selection mechanism and can return a collection of TextRange objects that represents discontinuous selections.
>
> But as of today IE doesn't, and I don't know of any other host application that does. Or indeed of any other browser than Firefox 3 that allows it.

Comment: Hi Jake, 

Thank you for the comment. Do host apps implement multiple selections by adding the selections to selectionservices? I am able to add them to the selectionservices but I am not don't know how to turn on the selection for them.

Comment: Sorry, unknown, I am simple quoting bobince - however it looks from his answer that multiple selection, with or without selectionservices populated, IE simply will not support it.

Comment: Neither IE nor chrome. Only firefox supports multiple discontinuous selected ranges. I had code that highlighted search results and was disappointed that it only worked on firefox. Moreover, window.getSelection().addRange(r) changes the focus to the selected text in chrome. I wonder why the method was called addRange while it's possible to select only one range?